# Two lines with the same number of address destination in ROUTING TABLE

Tags: networking, routes, ip

I am studying a particular case in routing table. As the title I have this table for a particular router in a net:

```
destin.IP       Mask             NextHop            Interface
193.14.5.160    255.255.255.0    ---.---.---.---    m0
193.14.5.192    255.255.255.0    ---.---.---.---    m1
111.0.0.0       255.0.0.0        ---.---.---.---    m0
192.16.7.0      255.255.255.0    111.15.17.32       m0
194.17.21.0     255.255.255.0    111.20.18.14       m0
194.17.21.16    255.255.255.0    111.20.18.14       m0
192.16.7.0      255.255.255.0    111.20.18.14       m0
194.17.21.0     255.255.255.0    111.15.17.32       m0
194.17.21.16    255.255.255.0    111.15.17.32       m0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0          111.30.31.18       m0
```

In that table there are lines with the same IP address like

```
192.16.7.0      255.255.255.0    111.15.17.32       m0
```

and

```
192.16.7.0      255.255.255.0    111.20.18.14       m0
```

in this case which of the two lines is chosen for routing? Why?

ps: It is actually an exercise. I try to share the track on dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1w3h0e7wp4eyb6/PSR-Esercitazione-Integrativa.pdf?dl=0

please see the ex. number 2

Comment: It is actually an exercise. I try to share the track on dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1w3h0e7wp4eyb6/PSR-Esercitazione-Integrativa.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your OS/kernel/options.  Some round-robin, some take the first (or last) found, etc.

However, there is also critical information missing from your routing table, probably.  Most systems also have a weight or metric on routes which can prioritize one route over the other.

The output of `ip route` on my system shows

```
  default via 168.13.96.1 dev optdmz 
  default via 166.14.88.1 dev dmz  metric 10 
  default via 168.13.96.1 dev optdmz  metric 20
```

The metric shows which route will be chosen out of "three" options (though one is duplicated). Lowest number wins.

Running `ip route get 192.16.7.5` (if you have that program) will show which route is selected.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/372504/round-robin-default-gateways-on-linux for information on round-robin routes.

Comment: It is actually an exercise. I try to share the track on dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1w3h0e7wp4eyb6/PSR-Esercitazione-Integrativa.pdf?dl=0

Comment: the ex. n.2 ask to write a routing table for router R1 in the network

Comment: @gpiscite: secondary sources to more fully explain your question, especially ones which require accounts to get the data, are frowned upon.  Put everything necessary to answer the question in the question.  But more to the point, it is irrelevant to answer your question (which I did).  However, to answer the question you wanted to ask but did not, you should either select the route which is closest from the perspective of the router you are projecting to, or if equal cost put both in, or put multiple routes in with metrics/weights (if that feature is available to you).

Comment: @gpiscite: Remember to accept the answer if it is correct.  You don't seem to do that very often.